# Wired Internet doesn't work on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, internet

Wired internet works on Windows but doesn't work on Ubuntu 12.04. I set it up manually. I am sure I did everything correctly. It even says `Connection established` but Internet doesn't work in any program.

I installed it on my PC. I didn't delete Windows yet.

My settings:

`IPv4`

`IP: 192.168.1.2`
`Netmask: 255.255.255.0` 
`Gateway: 192.168.1.1` 
`DNS servers: 213.145.129.20,213.145.129.19`

My router: `TP-Link TD-w8101g`

Answer (score 3):

Open the **terminal** and type in the following

```
ping 192.168.1.1
```

You should get replies not ***host not found*** or ***request timed out***. I am assuming the 192.168.1.1 is your router's IP address.

If the above worked it means it's connected to the router. Next try ping google servers and see if you are able to

```
ping www.google.com
```

if that works you should be able to access the internet but if it doesn't there might be a problem with DNS. If so try pinging the IP address of google servers just to make sure it can be reached via IP address

```
ping 8.8.8.8
```

*(this is a google DNS server IP address which doesn't change)*

If that works you have your answer... DNS issue. If it doesn't work then check the resolv configuration file to see what the default nameserver is set to and change it to your router. The resolv.conf (base) can be accessed by typing

```
sudo nano /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base
```

and change the name-server to your router's IP address as

**nameserver 192.168.1.1**

Now restart your computer and test again.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your problem is with the DNS server.  Look at this post [internet access problem in 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126743/internet-access-problem-in-12-04) for the solution to that problem.

Comment: Now, it's not DNS problem. It's router problem. I think there are no drivers for my router in Ubuntu

Comment: @Bakai Routers don't require drivers. A router is not a peripheral device that you attach to a computer for the computer to operate. It is a separate network device, that communicates with your computer via networking. Some routers have a USB port where you can connect them to a Windows computer and configure them. But you don't have to use that--you can reconfigure your router over the network, once connected to it, by accessing its setup page in a web browser. (Put the gateway IP in the address bar.) If you can't access that, you might need *network card* drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Your IP address information appears to be correct, but I would verify that the router's address is actually "192.168.1.1," as you have it listed (this is the Gateway address).  Some routers use 192.168.2.1, or some other 192.168.x.x address.  Also, if you have other machines on your network, and you have DHCP enabled on your router, you might already have another machine with the same address (192.168.1.2). This will prevent your connection from working properly.

Unless you MUST have a static IP address, I recommend using DHCP, as this is the easiest way to set up your network properly.

Answer (score 0):

Check your configuration on router.your router to laptop connection is perfect, but due to wrong configuration it may not able to share internet to your laptop or pc.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem. I edited the wired connection using the default GUI. Under IPv6 Settings, I set the Method to "Ignore." This solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. My PC and other phones and tablet connected to the same wireless router. Only the PC with Ubuntu 12.04 can not connect to the internet. What works for me is:

Get to the Edit Wired connection dialog, select IPV4 Settings tab

- On Method: select the "Automatic (DHCP) addresses only"
- Enter the DNS Servers: as your wireless router IP. i.e.: 192.168.0.1
- Check on the "Require IPV4 addressing..."
- Save then disconnect and reconnect again. Then, it works like a charm...

Hope this might help.