# Connected to the Internet but can't download softwares

Tags: apt

I am using wifi connection. I am using my Internet smoothly on Ubuntu. Downloading directly from server and everything goes on smoothly, but when I open terminal window to download VLC (other softwares also), the following error appears:

```
Failed to download repository information.
Check your Internet connection.
No address associated with hostname
W:Failed to fetch Something wicked happened resolving 'in.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
W:Failed to fetch Something wicked happened resolving 'security.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
W:Failed to fetch Something wicked happened resolving 'extras.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
```

Can You help me with this error.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix "-5 No address associated with hostname error" while updating?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142508/how-to-fix-5-no-address-associated-with-hostname-error-while-updating)

Answer (score 0):

> check my post in [Wired Internet doesn't work on ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/127678/wired-internet-doesnt-work-on-ubuntu-12-04/170731#170731)

If you have set up a static IP addressing you may have to look up the DNS Server that you set up in the interfaces conf, but if you left it as dynamic (DHCP) then check the resolv config (don't modify the resolv.conf as your settings will not me maintained. Modify the BASE file as my suggestion at the link above.

Comment if you need further help