# ubuntu 12.04 server doesn't resolve local domain name

Tags: networking, dns, resolv.conf

After apt-get upgrade this morning, my Ubuntu 12.04 web server does no longer resolve a domain name hosted on it.

I also received the error message:

```
"resolvconf: Error: /etc/resolv.conf isn't a symlink, not doing anything."
```

I found this question [NetworkManager not populating resolv.conf](https://askubuntu.com/questions/137037/network-manager-not-populating-resolv-conf) but the solutions provided there did not resolve the problem.

Creating the symlink  in fact caused websites to load very slowly, so I assume there is some sort of (reverse?) DNS lookup not working, when I create the symlink.

Comment: Look up my post here http://askubuntu.com/questions/127678/wired-internet-doesnt-work-on-ubuntu-12-04/170731#170731 and let me know if that worked for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running "dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf" sets up the symlink /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf.  After this you should reboot.

If websites are slow to *start* loading then this could indicate that a nameserver listed in resolv.conf is not responding. The glibc resolver(3) tries the first listed nameserver and waits five seconds before trying the next listed nameserver.

Also try commenting out "dns=dnsmasq" in /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf and running "restart network-manager". This disables the local NetworkManager-controlled dnsmasq instance, thus eliminating it as a possible cause of your problem.

If websites are not slow to start loading but load slowly after starting then this is most likely not a name resolution problem.