# internet connection doesnt work properly

Tags: xubuntu

I have a problem with my internet connection on xubuntu 13.04. Sometimes it works perfectly, but sometimes it is very slow or doesnt work at all and I have to refresh page or restart installation in software center for several times. I have a dual boot with win7 and there is everything alright. Please help.

Comment: You didn't specify if you wireless or wired connection.

Comment: Possible duplication: [Internet doesn't work](http://askubuntu.com/questions/127678/wired-internet-doesnt-work-on-ubuntu-12-04)